# Print multiple pages with C# and microsoft PDF printer

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, printdocument

I'm trying to print several lines in a PDF document using the PrintDocument class and sending it to the Microsoft PDF printer. When no more lines fit on the same page, I'm setting the HasMorePages property of the PrintPageEventArgs to true. And resetting my Y coordinate to the page beginning, but, although the result is a PDF with multiple pages, all lines are printed on the first page, and the other pages are blank pages...

Im guessing that if I send de document to a real printer, it would be ok, because a physical printer cant go back to the first sheet of paper and print it over... but on the case of the PDFPrinter all lines are overlapped...

Any idea how could I fix this?

Comment: Could you please post the code of the `PrintPage` handler? Maybe you have the `e.HasMorePages = true` in a loop? If so, do you `break` or `return` right after setting the property?

Comment: Oh man you're right! I had the e.HasMorePages in a loop. I added the break and that did the trick!

Comment: @dr.null could you put your comment on an answer so I can mark it as the solution? :)

Comment: It was just a _maybe_ since there's no code to tell. As it worked for you, kindly post the answer and accept it so we can find it later. Good luck.